# Disallow sensitive file from browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

Browserify allows using the same module on both server and client, which is good.

However some files I don't want included in a browserify bundle, for example a properties file containing sensitive data. Obviously I wouldn't intentionally include it, but I want to go a step further and prevent it from even being possible, say by accident or by a developer who's unfamiliar with the setup.

Right now I have this:

```
// fail browserify but not node
try { require('./kill/browserify'); }
catch(ex) {}
```

...which I think should work since node includes dynamically but browserify includes statically, but I was wondering if there was a less hackish way? Like some sort of comment directive:

```
// is something like this possible?
/* @browserify disallow */
```

Answer (score 2):

How about [exclude](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bexcludefile)?

> --exclude, -u  Omit a file from the output bundle. Files can be globs.
>
> If your code tries to require() that file it will throw unless you've provided another mechanism for loading it.

The above answer works **only at runtime** as @greim mentioned. Another solution that should work at bundle time is to use a browserify transformer to alias your protected file to something that does not exist.

Using aliasify:

```
aliasify = require('aliasify').configure({
    aliases: {
        "file-protected": "./path/to/protected"
    }
});

var b = browserify();
b.transform(aliasify);
...
```

Comment: This would generate an error at runtime, but not at bundle time. So I wouldn't be able to fail a build using this technique, for example. The build would run happily and it would be up to QA or whoever to catch it in the wild.

Comment: Regarding using `aliasify`, I'll up-vote this as a working solution, however I also note that it's no less of a hack than the thing I came up with :)

Comment: @greim Yes its a hack, but it is a hack in your build rather than your code. I see it as a small improvement.